# Response.Redirect() in mobile ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, windows-mobile

I am developing a mobile web application using System.Web.Mobile namespace of ASP.NET.
I am facing problem with redirect to a different aspx page using Response.Redirect() while testing with dotmobi emulators with the error message:

> The requested item could not be loaded (status code 502)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Server.Transfer istead of response.redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both aspx pages have the correct content-type set, e.g:

`<%@ Page ContentType="application/xhtml+xml" %>`

As well as:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Status code 502: The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

Is the destination page within your website? Does it contain calls to external services / other servers?